# How to get Zend Studio to recognize and autocomplete functions in the global scope?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, zend-studio

Zend Studio underlines existing function names with yellow squiggly lines, even when I explicitly include a file that contains declaration of those functions.

**Example:**

[image: Zend Studio underlines existing method names]

It used to not do that and I was able to go to the function declaration names by right-click => Open Declaration.  Now I can't.  I do not know what had changed, it's just that one day those functions became underlined.

**How can I enable/configure/restore this feature?**

So far I have refreshed project, re-indexed project, re-imported the project, re-added file with function declarations hoping that will update the function database, included file with declarations explicitly.  I disabled and re-enabled  PHP Semantic Analysis.  None of those worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From top-level menu, go to

- Project
- Properties
- PHP
- Include Path
- Source
- Add Folder

Add folders where your source functions are, press OK, wait for project DLTK indexing to rebuild.  Voila!, no more squiggly lines and autocomplete works.

---

Even after the above worked, I still began to have other issues with my IDE, so what I did I completely uninstalled it, then reinstalled it, and re-created my workspace and re-downloaded my project from GitHub, and now things are back to normal.  I will have to reset my project-specific and Zend Studio and other settings though.